# $N$ bins, $m$ balls: Probability of any bin containing *exactly* $k$ balls.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, balls-in-bins

This is an extension to question [821984](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/821984/):

Given $N$ balls independently distributed randomly among $m$ bins, what is the probability that *at least one* bin gets exactly $k$ balls? And is this probability maximized when $N = k m$?

To be more clear, for fixed $N$ and $m$, there is for each integer $k$ a probability $P_{mN}(k)$ that at least one bin gets exactly $k$ balls.  Is it
true for all fixed $(N,m)$ that 
$$
\frac{N}{m} - 1 < k_0 : \max_k P_{mN}(k) = P_{mN}(k_0) < \frac{N}{m} + 1
$$

For example, for $m=3, N=7$ we get
$$
P_{37}(0) = \frac{127}{729}, 
P_{37}(1) = \frac{409}{729}, 
P_{37}(2) = \frac{462}{729}, 
P_{37}(3) = \frac{420}{729}, \\
P_{37}(4) = \frac{280}{729}, 
P_{37}(5) = \frac{84}{729}, 
P_{37}(6) = \frac{14}{729}, 
P_{37}(7) = \frac{1}{729}
$$
with the maximum occuring at $k=2$ which satisfies $\frac73 - 1 < 2 < \frac73+1$.

I can produce an expression for the probability, based on the probability that at least
  $r$ bins will contain exactly $k$ balls:
$$
P(k,m,N) = \frac{1}{m^N}\sum_{r=1}^{\lfloor N/k \rfloor}(-1)^r
\left( \begin{array}{c}m\\r\end{array} \right)
(m-r)^{N-rk}\prod_{s=0}^{r-1}
\left( \begin{array}{c}N-2s\\k\end{array} \right)
$$
(The minus signs come from the usual mantra of subtracing the double-counted overlap where two bins contain $k$ balls, then adding back the triple overlap, and so forth.)

But even after wandering around in Concrete Mathematics, I can't simplify this enough to answer the maximization question.

Comment: I don't know how to simplify that expression.  At this point, I'd take a step back and try to compute the probability that no bin contains k balls.

Comment: @Mark Fischler If $N$ balls are independently distributed randomly among $m$ bins, does it imply that any two final configurations, say for example if $m=3$, $\{k,1,n-(k+1)\}$ and $\{k,2,n-(k+2)\}$ are equally probable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this can be simplified.

For large values of $N,m$, an asympotic approximation is straighforward (Poissonization). Letting $\lambda = N/m$, $t = \lambda/k$:

$$P \approx  1- \left( \frac{e^{-\lambda} \lambda^k}{k!}\right)^m=\\
=1-  \left( \frac{k^k}{k!}\right)^m \left( t^k e^{-t k} \right)^m
$$

Regarding the last expression as a function of $t$, keeping $k,m$ fixed, we get the extremum at $t=1$, as expected ($N=k m$). At this point, the value of the probability can be further approximated by the Stirling approximation, giving:

$$ P_{max}\approx 1-  \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi k }}\right)^m$$

Comment: I believe the extremum at  $N = km$ holds even for small values of $m$ and $k$. But proving that is hard.

Answer (score 0):

We assume the $N$ balls are indistinguishible while the $m$ bins are distinguishible. So, if $m=2$ and $N\geq k$ there are two favorable outcomes: 
\begin{align*}
(k,N-k)\qquad\text{and}\qquad (N-k,k)
\end{align*}

> With this assumption the probability $P(k,m,N)$ is somewhat different than OPs formula and the probability will also in general **not be maximized** at $N=km$.
>
> We calculate the probability $P(k,m,N)$ by looking at the number of *favorable* outcomes, i.e. the number with at least one bin containing precisely $k$ balls and divide this number by the number of *all* possible outcomes.
>
> **Special case:** $P(k,1,N)$
>
> At first we look at the special case with $m=1$, i.e. there is only one bin. In this case there is only one favorable outcome, if the number $N$ of balls is equal to $k$.
>
> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> P(k,1,N)=\begin{cases}
> 1&\qquad N=k\\
> 0&\qquad \text{otherwise}\\
> \end{cases}
> \end{align*}
>
> **Special case: $1\leq N<k$**
>
> If the number $N$ of balls is less than the number $k$ we can't reach any favorable outcome and the probability is zero:
>   \begin{align*}
> P(k,m,N)=0\qquad\quad 1\leq N<k,m\geq 1
> \end{align*}

**General case: $m\geq 2, N\geq k$**

In the following we assume there are more than one bins availabe, i.e. $m\geq 2$ and the number $N$ of balls is at least $k$, i.e. $N\geq k$. The probability $P(k,m,N)$ is given by
\begin{align*}
P(k,m,N)&=
\left(\!\!\binom{m}{N}\!\!\right)^{-1}
\sum_{r=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{N}{k}\right\rfloor}
(-1)^{r+1}\binom{m}{r}\left(\!\!\binom{m-r}{N-rk}\!\!\right)\qquad N<km\tag{1}\\
\text{and}\\
P(k,m,N)&=\left(\!\!\binom{m}{N}\!\!\right)^{-1}\sum_{r=1}^{m-1}
(-1)^{r+1}\binom{m}{r}\left(\!\!\binom{m-r}{N-rk}\!\!\right)\\
&\qquad\qquad+(-1)^m\delta_{N,km}\left(\!\!\binom{m}{N}\!\!\right)^{-1}\quad\qquad\qquad\qquad N\geq km\tag{2}\\
\end{align*}

> The number of all possible outcomes is the number of multisets
>   \begin{align*}
> \left(\!\!\binom{m}{N}\!\!\right)=\binom{m+N-1}{m-1}
> \end{align*}
>   to distribute $N$ *indistinguishible* balls on $m$ *distinguishible* bins. If we select one bin containing exactly $k$ balls, there are $m-1$ bins left which contain $m-N$ balls. Since we can select a bin in $\binom{m}{1}$ different ways, the number of possible outcomes is
>   \begin{align*}
> \binom{m}{1}\left(\!\!\binom{m-1}{N-k}\!\!\right)
> \end{align*}
>   The expression $\left(\!\!\binom{m-1}{N-k}\!\!\right)$ contains outcomes whereby some other bins may also contain precisely $k$ balls. In order to respect this surplus we have to apply the *[inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle#Statement)*
>   as indicated by OP.
>   The general term is
>   \begin{align*}
> (-1)^{r+1}\binom{m}{r}\left(\!\!\binom{m-r}{N-rk}\!\!\right)
> =(-1)^{r+1}\binom{m}{r}\binom{m-r+N-rk-1}{m-r-1}
> \end{align*}
>   with the sign $(-1)^{r+1}$ indicating the current surplus or shortage. The general term compensates for $r$ bins each containing precisely $k$ balls leaving $N-rk$ balls to distribute on the remaining $m-r$ bins.
>
> This strategy is feasible up to $N=mk-1$ balls in which case the last term of (1) contains $m-1$ bins with precisely $k$ balls and one bin contains the other $N-k(m-1)$ balls.
>
> If the number of balls increases, i.e. $N\geq mk$, the upper limit of the sum (2) is always $m-1$, since we always have to correct the surplus resp. shortage of up to $m-1$ bins.
>
> In case of $N=km$ balls there is a special favorable outcome, namely *all* $m$ bins contain precisely $k$ balls. This is possible only in case $N=km$. For all greater values of $N$, i.e. $N>km$ no more than $m-1$ bins can contain precisely $k$ balls. This is realized by multiplying $(-1)^{m}$ with the *[Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta)* $$\delta_{N,km}=\begin{cases}1&\qquad N=km\\0&\qquad\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

**Probabilities with $N=km$:**

Calculation  of the probability $P(k,m,N)$ for small $k,m$ and $N$ shows that  besides the trivial case $P(k,1,N)$ the maximum was not reached at $N=km$.

In the following table we see for small $m,k$ and $N$ the probability $P(k,m,km)$ and another value of $N$ with higher probability.

\begin{array}{rrrlrrrlrrrl}
k&m&N&P(k,m,N)\qquad&\qquad k&m&N&P\qquad&\qquad k&m&N&P\\
\hline\\
2&3&3&0.6\qquad&\qquad3&3&5&0.42857\qquad&\qquad4&3&7&0.33333\\
2&3&6&0.46429\qquad&\qquad3&3&9&0.34545\qquad&\qquad4&3&12&0.27473\\
\\
2&4&3&0.6\qquad&\qquad3&4&5&0.42857\qquad&\qquad4&4&7&0.33333\\
2&4&8&0.51515\qquad&\qquad3&4&12&0.39780\qquad&\qquad4&4&16&0.32301\\
\\
2&5&7&0.60606\qquad&\qquad3&5&11&0.47253\qquad&\qquad4&5&15&0.38700\\
2&5&10&0.59041\qquad&\qquad3&5&15&0.46207\qquad&\qquad4&5&20&0.37841\\
\end{array}

> The last table entry with $k=4$ and $m=5$ gives
>
> \begin{align*}
> P(4,5,15)&=\left(\!\!\binom{5}{15}\!\!\right)^{-1}
> \sum_{r=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{15}{4}\right\rfloor}
> (-1)^{r+1}\binom{5}{r}\left(\!\!\binom{5-r}{15-4r}\!\!\right)\\
> &=\binom{19}{4}^{-1}\sum_{r=1}^{3}
> (-1)^{r+1}\binom{5}{r}\binom{18-6r}{4-r}\\
> &=\binom{19}{4}^{-1}\left(\binom{5}{1}\binom{14}{3}-\binom{5}{2}\binom{9}{2}+\binom{5}{3}\binom{4}{1}\right)\\
> &=\frac{125}{323}=0.38700\\
> P(4,5,20)&=\left(\!\!\binom{4}{20}\!\!\right)^{-1}
> \left(\sum_{r=1}^{5-1}
> (-1)^{r+1}\binom{5}{r}\left(\!\!\binom{5-r}{20-4r}\!\!\right)+(-1)^{m}\right)\\
> &=\binom{23}{3}^{-1}\left(\sum_{r=1}^{3}
> (-1)^{r+1}\binom{5}{r}\binom{24-5r}{4-r}+1\right)\\
> &=\binom{24}{4}^{-1}\left(\binom{5}{1}\binom{19}{3}-\binom{5}{2}\binom{14}{2}+\binom{5}{3}\binom{9}{1}-\binom{5}{4}\binom{4}{0}+1\right)\\
> &=\frac{4021}{10626}=0.37841\\
> \end{align*}
>
> and we see $P(4,5,20)<P(4,5,15)$.

Comment: That shows the probability is not maximized over possible values of $N$ for fixed $m$ and $k$ at $N = km$. The question should have read that I wanted to show that for fixed $N$ and $m$ such that $N/m =r$ the in $k$ maximum is reached at $k=r$.  I will clarify in the question.